# During Settings Migration (Magento Migration Tool) --> [ERROR]: Source and Destination documents are not mapped: store, store_group, store_website

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool

```
Magento 1.9.4 --> Magento 2.4.2-p1
```

I've setup a fresh domain, installed Magento 2.4.2-p1 via Softaculous. I've modified config.xml with the correct settings including the source_prefix and dest_prefix of the databases and now when I run the Settings Magento Migration tool via the following command:

> php bin/magento migrate:settings
> vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.4.0/config.xml

I get these Errors:

```
[mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Stores Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec

[ERROR]: Source documents are not mapped: 

core_store,core_store_group,core_website

[ERROR]: Destination documents are not mapped: 

store,store_group,store_website
```

*I haven't set up the store, store_group, store_website yet on the new Magento* - **do I have to do that BEFORE I run the Magento Migration tool?** I think there may be an issue with the names of the stores/store_groups/store_websites as on the original Magento 1.9.4 system it has numbers in the names and that is not possible on Magento 2.4.2-p1? **Any suggestions on how to proceed?**

---

Updated on July 13th, 2021:

Apparently, this error happens when M1 or M2 use prefix in table names. I have added the prefix in the config.xml file in the following tags and that fixed the problem:

<source_prefix />
<dest_prefix />

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this error happens when M1 or M2 use prefix in table names. I have added the prefix in the config.xml file in the following tags and that fixed the problem:

```
<source_prefix />
<dest_prefix />
```

The migration then ran successfully. I didn't initially realize that was the issue as I got the Error about the table prefix at the same time as this Error.